# Binding reusuable components to different contents

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Lets say I have a dropdown control with auto complete feature as shown

COMPONENT:

```
import {Component, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    host: {
        '(document:click)': 'handleClick($event)',
    },
    template: `
    <div class="container" >
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input id="country" type="text" class="validate filter-input" [(ngModel)]=query (keyup)=filter()>
          <label for="country">Country</label>
        </div>
        <div class="suggestions" *ngIf="filteredList.length > 0">
            <ul *ngFor="#item of filteredList" >
                <li >
                    <a (click)="select(item)">{{item}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>


     </div>
        `
})

export class AppComponent {
    public query = '';
    public countries =  ["Albania","Andorra","Belarus","Canada"];
    public filteredList = [];
    public elementRef;

    constructor(myElement: ElementRef) {
        this.elementRef = myElement;
    }

    filter() {
        if (this.query !== ""){
            this.filteredList = this.countries.filter(function(el){
                return (el.toLowerCase().substr(0,this.query.length) === this.query.toLowerCase()) == true;

            }.bind(this));
        }else{
            this.filteredList = [];
        }
    }

    select(item){
        this.query = item;
        this.filteredList = [];
    }

    handleClick(event){
       var clickedComponent = event.target;
       var inside = false;
       do {
           if (clickedComponent === this.elementRef.nativeElement) {
               inside = true;
           }
          clickedComponent = clickedComponent.parentNode;
       } while (clickedComponent);
        if(!inside){
            this.filteredList = [];
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
```

How can I make this component reusable so that I can use it inside a form binding different contents. Like Country/State/City or may be non related data in sign up page created using angular2 component.

Comment: Pointing to third party sites for examples helps no one in the future when those examples disappear. Create a relevant example here.

Comment: Updated with actual reference code if that helps not closing question

Answer (score 0):

- Implement [`ControlValueAccessor`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/ControlValueAccessor-interface.html) to make it work with `[(ngModel)]="..."`
  As an example see https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/22916bb5d1abf2818d7d8d99d39605af251f42e4/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/checkbox_value_accessor.ts
- Make the properties you want to fill from the outside inputs

```
@Input() public query = '';
@Input() public countries;
```

then you can use your control like

```
<my-comp [query]="abc" [countries]="['Albania','Andorra','Belarus','Canada']"
```

- Create an output for the result

```
@Output() queryChange:EventEmitter<String> = new EventEmitter<String>();
```

to be able to bind the result like

```
<my-comp [(query)]="valueProp"
```